# Zend modules: How to fix routes for actions in modules?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I am refactoring my code for splitting in to Modules.
I had before `http://my.site/bug/list`
After moving the bugController to `/application/modules/Bug`

I have now: http://my.site/Bug/index/list

How to configure the routes in order to have:
http://my.site/Bug/list

thanks Arman.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "list" controller inside Bug module and move all code of old bug::list action into new Bug::list::index action. Another way is to deal with route definitions, but this way is harder.

Comment: I have there edit, delete, update actions, to create a controller for every action is not so good solution.